# ListView in BlackBerry 10 Cascades

Tags: blackberry-10

I need to update the list view values from c++ function when the list view was created in BB10. Can anyone suggest me about this regards.

Answer (score 2):

There are few ways to create ListView in blackberry 10 i.e. using **QML**, by using **C++** or by using **BOTH**.

Please have look at [these examples](http://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/sampleapps/).

In above link they provided 1 example called **Cascades Cookbook** this 
example available in two flavor i.e. in C++ or in QML in that they had used ListView and other examples will also help you.

Answer (score 1):

The ListView takes the data for display from a DataModel object. The method of updating the data, either item by item or wholesale, would be determined by the specific DataModel being used. You should look at the API documentation for that model.